# Checking diff exit status in a script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, exit-code

On the command line, after using diff on two files that differ, the command

```
echo $?
```

reports back '1'.  When I try the same in a script, as follows:

```
echo "` diff $F1 $F2`"   
rv=$?  
if [[ $rv == 1 ]]  
then    
    echo "failed"    
fi
```

then I never print 'failed' (even for differing files). Note that this is the bash shell, so the grammar should be fine (eg, if I check for '0' instead, it always prints).

How can I check if the diff command discovered differences, and process conditionally on that?

This is under Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Use `cmp` instead of `diff` if you are only interested in return codes.

Comment: And `echo $(diff)` returns the exit code from `echo`, not from `diff`.

Comment: @RedX: your second comment answers why it doesn't work, thanks. But I would like to print the differences first, but also keep track of how many comparisons failed. Do you see an easy way to do that?

Comment: `diff` does not output the count of mismatches AFAIK. `var=$(diff "$F1" "$F2"); ret=$?; echo "$var"; if (($ret == 0)); then echo "same"; else echo "not same"; fi`

Comment: Not tested:
`TMPFILE=.tmp.$$; if diff "${F1}" "${F2}" > "${TMPFILE}; then echo "There were $(wc -l "${TMPFILE}") differences;"; cat "${TMPFILE}"; else echo "Same same!"; fi ; rm -f "${TMPFILE}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do this instead.

```
echo "`diff $F1 $F2`"
diff $F1 $F2 > /dev/null 2>&1
rv=$?
...
```

because `$?` is get set to 0 by the successful execution of `echo`.

And if you don't want to run `diff` twice you could do this too ..

```
   diff $F1 $F2 > /tmp/thediff 2>&1
   if [ $? != 0 ]
   then
      cat /tmp/thediff
   fi
```

Comment: @ꜱᴀᴍᴏᴛʜ then the echo would not print the result

Comment: @ceving yeah I run diff twice ... so what?

Comment: @RedCricket Your question is a -1 worth.

Comment: @ceving So what's you solution then?

Comment: @RedCricket `echo $rv`

Comment: That does the trick! And a good standard trick (?) learned.Thanks! (it's clever and useful, so don't understand the confusion about the answer :))

Comment: Using temp files with fixed names has the disadvantage of not enabling you to use this script in any kind of parallel work.

Comment: Race conditions. There's no guarantee that the two invocations of `diff` will have the same result.

Comment: Well it just goes to show you, it's always something, you either got a toenail in your hamburger or toilet paper clinging to your shoe. Roseanne Roseannadanna

Comment: Andrew Medico's answer below is the better answer.

Answer (score 6):

You're not seeing the return value from `diff` because the last command run is actually `echo` and you're seeing its return value. You should be able to achieve the desired effect with the following code (capturing and then echoing the output of `diff` is unnecessary - just let it write to stdout):

```
diff $F1 $F2
rv=$?  
if [[ $rv == 1 ]]  
then    
    echo "failed"    
fi
```

Also, note that `diff` returns a value greater than one on error (`0` indicates identical files, `1` indicates different files). You may want to check for and handle that case.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to also print the diff; so @RedCricket 's answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: The `echo "\`cmd\`"` construct is pointless. You're capturing what `cmd` wrote to `stdout` and... immediately writing it to `stdout`. As written, it accomplishes nothing (except - as you've discovered - making impossible to get the return value of `cmd`).

Comment: @RedCricket Agreed, though RedX's answer also has merit for (partially) addressing the count-the-differences requirement. You could help address that by updating your answer with a preamble that points to this (and also RedX's) answer.

Answer (score 5):

From your comment:

> But I would like to print the differences first, but also keep track of how many comparisons failed.

I don't know if diff outputs the number of differences in the exit code. I think not. But you could count the lines maybe...

Here is how you can store the exit code and count the number of different lines

```
var=$(diff "$F1" "$F2")
#store diff exit code
exit_code=$?
# remember that this is not the same as count of differences
lines_output_by_diff=$(wc -l <<< "$var")

echo "$var"

if (($exit_code == 0)); then
  echo "same"
else
  echo "not same"
fi
```

Comment: Very nice! That does even more than I want. Diff is binary (as you probably know): 1 - differences, 0 - none.

Comment: @gnometorule: If you replace `wc -l` with `grep -c '^[0-9]'`, you will get the actual _difference count_.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be because, in your script, `$?` is the return status of your `echo` line (not the previous program), and echo will probably always work and return `0`.